# How to Change C# Code

Tags: c#

my friend showed something good last week witch is he was able to change the c language
 codes from:

```
int a = 1 + 1;
```

To:

```
num a =1+1;
```

what he did is he changes the "int" to "num". So i wonder if there is a way to do this on c#
Thanks

Comment: did it execute without errors?

Comment: I don't want to sound rude but does this make any sense?

Comment: But, this is interesting to solve, even though it does make any sense

Answer (score 8, accepted):

look at the [using Directive (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) on MSDN for more information

this is how you do it

```
using num = System.Int32;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            num a = 1 + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this is how you do it but, more importantly, don't. Because all it does is make your code harder to read.

Comment: you might want to change it  `System.Int32`

Comment: @AntP, i totally agree with you... but let the programmer decide what is best for him and hope that the maintainer of the code know this.

Comment: You might want to add a link to the msdn for alias' if op wants to read more about it and what its doing